# Tensor Flow using old graph instead of new one

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have retrained two different classification models models using [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py).

For predicting labels for two images I have created getLabel method from [Label_image.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/label_image.py) as follows:

```
def getLabel(localFile, graphKey, labelKey):

    image_data_str = tf.gfile.FastGFile(localFile, 'rb').read()

    # Loads label file, strips off carriage return
    label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                   in tf.gfile.GFile(labelKey)]

    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(graphKey, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess:
        # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data_str})

        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
        series = []
        count = 1
        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            if count==1:
                label = human_string
                count+=1
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
            series.append({"name": human_string, "data": [score * 100]})
        sess.close()

    return label, series
```

And I am calling them as

```
 label,series = predict.getLabel(localFile, 'graph1.pb', 'labels1.txt')
 label,series = predict.getLabel(localFile, 'graph2.pb', 'labels2.txt')
```

But for the second function call it is using the old graph i.e. graph1.pb & it is giving below error since model 1 has more categories than model 2.

```
human_string = label_lines[node_id]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not able to understand why is this happening. Can someone tell how to load second graph??

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where is `predict` defined?

Comment: predict is another file i.e. predict.py which contains getLabel() function

Comment: I noticed this as well. Something about node_id has values which are unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what is happening is that you are calling the same session for both calls to `predict.getFinalLabel`. What you should do is define two separate sessions, and initialize each separately (e.g. have `predict1.getFinalLabel` and `predict2.getFinalLabel`). If you post more of your code, I can provide more detail and code.

Comment: This is the all logic. Remaining part is for loading image. And after functions calls displaying results.